# AUC metric is zero for Keras model with fractional labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, auc

In this simple example, the AUC is zero although the prediction is perfect (loss 0, accuracy 1):

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# enable debugging of tf.keras.metrics.AUC.update_state and .result
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

# simple model connecting a scalar input to a scalar output
layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=1)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=layer, outputs=layer)

# prepare data: [0.1, 0.2, ... 0.9]
data = np.arange(1, 10) / 10
print(f"data = {data}")

# compile and fit model using accuracy and AUC metrics
model.compile(metrics=["categorical_accuracy", "AUC"])
history = model.fit(x=data, y=data, verbose=0)
print(f"metrics = {history.history}")
```

Output:

```
data = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]
metrics = {'loss': [0.0], 'categorical_accuracy': [1.0], 'auc': [0.0]}
```

The reason is two-fold:

1. `keras.utils.metrics_utils.update_confusion_matrix_variables` casts all labels to bool, so all labels belong to the "true" class.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/834e7ddb83/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py#L380

2. Since `self.false_positives` is all zero, the result which is proportional to `x == fp_rate` is zero, too:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/834e7ddb83/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L2248-L2250

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/834e7ddb83/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L2285-L2287

I wonder what I should do about this. The docs say that for

> a best approximation of the real AUC, `predictions` should be distributed approximately uniformly in the range [0, 1]

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/834e7ddb83/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L1875-L1879

which is the case. I think the authors did not envisage people doing element-wise manual label smoothing (which I do to implement sample-wise label smoothing).

The problem can be reduced to this, which prints `AUC = 0.0` as well:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# prepare data: [0.1, 0.2, ... 0.9]
data = np.arange(1, 10) / 10
print(f"data = {data}")

# compute AUC metric
m = tf.keras.metrics.AUC(num_thresholds=3)
m.update_state(data, data)
print(f"AUC = {m.result().numpy()}")
```

Is this expected? If so, is there some kind of *categorical AUC* that I could use?

Comment: (The issue appears in TF `2.4.1` as well as in `2.5.0rc0`.)